# All tabs are refreshing continuously using ABP commercial

Tags: angular, refresh-token, abp

We use ABP framework commercial version.

When the user opens more than two tabs simultaneously, after a while, all tabs start to refresh continuously. As we investigated, this issue probably is related to the refresh token mechanism, in which all tabs have shared one Local Storage in the browser. There is a chance that tabs override token values of each other. Our first guess was that we might have changed the structure of ABP which led to this problem, but when we checked the default project, we realized that after the end of the access token, the users in the adjacent tabs are automatically logged out. This is a problem in itself and we don't want the user to log out after each access token ends. Logging out of the user should happen when the refresh token expires.

We don't have access directly to change the behavior of changing tokens because ABP uses its own identity package.

How can we solve this and stop the infinite loop of refreshing the tabs?

the package.json file and Angular and ABP packages are like below:

[image: package.json]

Comment: *The question should be updated to include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.*

Comment: Since that's probably not possible (without violating your commercial license), you should ask on [support.abp.io](https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions) instead.